# MTURK: Amount of variables varies

Tags: mechanicalturk

Using variables in a new HIT. Variables come from CSV file and are defined like so:

```
variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4
value,value,value,value
value,value,value,value
...
```

And in HIT they are called like:

```
${variable1}
${variable2}
${variable3}
${variable4}
```

(One line for one hit)

My question is, can I have amount of variables that vary? How to call them in HIT?

Example:

```
variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4,variable5
value,value,value
value,value,value,value,value
...
```

Comment: You could leave values of some variables blank, or you could create your own HITs via the API.

Comment: Till now, this seems to be the only reasonable answer. I didn't get any response even on AWS forums...